# Verificacion de un Checkbox

Tags: java, android

Buenas tengo una consulta acerca de un CheckBox de Aceptación de Condiciones de Uso. Tengo 2 cajas de texto (EditText) y un CheckBox. Lo que necesito lograr es que si las 2 cajas de texto están vacías y el checkbox no esta "checkeado" me devuelva un mensaje de error.

El punto es que ya logro esto, pero si completo los campos de texto y el checkbox aun esta sin marcar el proceso igual es realizado cosa que no deberia ocurrir ya que primero debo aceptaro las Condiciones de Uso

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(saldo.getText.toString().equals("") && monto.getText.toString().equals("") && !checkBox.isChecked()) {
                       //Mostrar Error
                    } else {
                      // Hacer operacion
                    }

            });
```

Comment: Puedes explicar un poco mejor tu problema. La verdad es que no entiendo bien lo que quieres lograr.

Comment: @David Ok, voy a escribirte a tu correo ya que veo que dejaste uno en tu perfil para explicarlo mejor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tu error esta en que usas el operador && cuando lo que debes usar es ||**, esto es porque tú quieres que si no ha pasado cualquiera de esas 3 condiciones no se produzca la operación, con tu código solo consigues que no se cumpla la operación siempre y cuando no se den las 3 condiciones a la vez.

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View view) {
        if (saldo.getText.toString().isEmpty() || monto.getText.toString().isEmpty()) {
            //Mostrar Error no has rellenado campos 
        } else if (!checkBox.isChecked()) {
            //Mostrar Error no has aceptado las condiciones de uso 
        } else {
            // Hacer operacion 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ahora si tiene sentido, a parte soy algo nuevo y me olvidaba que podía usar esta opción "||"

Comment: De nada, un saludo!